# Waiting while a web elements state changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

I need to wait while a web elements state changes (class attribute):

```
while(!$('#modal').hasClass('is-active')) {
        //Need to wait 500ms here
      }
```

I can leave it empty but it would use too much resource. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: sound like jQuery thing instead of Node.JS. cant you just use `if($('#modal').hasClass('is-active')) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to `emit an event` when the `modal` changes state. If you're using bootstrap(which I think you're doing), it provides couple of events.

> **`show.bs.modal`**: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element
>   is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.
>
> **`shown.bs.modal`**: This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If
>   caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   relatedTarget property of the event.

You can do use the event in your app.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

You can refer here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

I don't know what it has to do with Node.JS cause most probably you're using it in the `view` (of MVC) or other frameworks like react, angular, vue, or maybe simple jQuery